# CheckBoxList Value gets overwritten by Text on DataBind ASP.NET web forms

Tags: c#, data-binding, webforms, checkboxlist

I have a `CheckBoxList` that I want to populate using a collection of ListItems with `Text` and `Values` defined.

```
var temp = types.Select(x => new ListItem(x["Description"].ToString(), x["TypeCode"].ToString()));
chbox.DataSource = temp;
chbox.DataBind();
```

The ListItems in `temp` have the correct `Text` and `Value` property values, but after `chbox.DataBind()`, all of the `Value` properties are populated with the `Text` property value.

So if the ListItems in `temp` look like

```
Text    Value
LetterA A
LetterB B
```

The ListItems in `chbox.Items` look like

```
Text    Value
LetterA LetterA
LetterB LetterB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to define

```
 DataTextField="TextField" DataValueField="ValueField"
```

as shown below:

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataTextField="TextField" DataValueField="ValueField">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Please check out [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)